# Raspian apt returns to prompt without doing anything - any ideas?

Tags: raspbian-jessie, apt

`apt` and the associated tools are not working using any of them: `sudo apt`, `apt-get`, `apt-config`, `aptitude`, ..., just returns me to the prompt. I checked `/var/log/apt` and nothing is getting written to the logs.

Any idea what is going on and how to fix it?

Output from `uname -a`:

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.1.14+ #4 PREEMPT Wed Mar 23 15:16:24 UTC 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You are obviously running an obsolete OS (which has probably never been updated)

Comment: Okay, and . . .

Comment: Start by providing some information and the commands you are trying and any errors

Comment: Is there a reason you can’t just reflash your SD Card with the latest Raspbian Stretch?

Comment: I probably can just overwrite the card.  It have a small HAT with a 3" screen, I'll track down the packages for that and reinstall afterward.      What I was curious about is that is just stopped one day.   For example 'sudo apt --help' returns to the prompt with no output.

Answer (score 2):

If `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list` are empty then you get the behavior you described. **apt** tools just return to the prompt because there is no repository to manage. I don't know what operating system and version do you use but with **Raspbian Stretch** the list files should contain:

```
rpi ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi

rpi ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
```

Comment: Yes these files are populated,  pointed to jessie archives.  I was editing them, so I'll take a look to make sure I didn't fat finger them.  Thank you.